# How to show y axis text labels instead of the count in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am fairly new to power bi and I am trying to create a stacked bar chart of two columns ( one column contains type: individual, Business and government. a second column contains new connections, complaints , etc) I want to create a stacked bar chart with the type on the x-axis and the reason on the y axis. so what I did is this:

[image: stacked bar chart]

the x axis shows the 3 types: government, individual and business but the y axis shows 0,50,100 and not the actual labels ( new connections, complaints,...). is there a way to show the text ( new connections, complaints, etc) on the y-axis instead of 0,50,100

this is the columns:

[image: columns]

I tried to change the count in the y-axis but there was no button for it, I need to change the y axis labels to the text inside the actual column instead of the current numbers, is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can't. Y-axis has to be numbers. Btw., you are using a 100% stacked column chart, hence the numbers 0%, 50% and 100%.

Answer (score -1):

Hello there should be a button for it as in the image below.
[image]

Like the red arrow shows, and you can change it there

Comment: Change to what? call_reason is not a numerical field, so the only available aggregation is Count.

Comment: i see now, then what you can do is create a measure with count distinct for each type of the call_reason

Comment: Did you even read the question?